# Searching for records with the same date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

What is the best way to determine records from the same table with the same dates.

I have 2 rows from my instalments table:

```
ORDER_1  | 13 | Paid | 2017-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
ORDER_2  | 14 | Paid | 2017-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
```

I need to be able to show all the instalments where the date is the same.

I have tried:

```
SELECT *  FROM ORDER_INSTALMENT WHERE DATEDUE = DATEDUE
```

Comment: what is all of your field name?

Comment: OrderID, InstalmentID, InstalmentSatus, DateDue

Comment: Aside: If `DateDue` is really a date it should be a `Date`, not a `DateTime` or other data type that includes a time component.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.OrderID, a.InstalmentID, a.InstalmentSatus, a.DateDue
FROM ORDER_INSTALMENT AS a INNER JOIN ORDER_INSTALMENT AS b
ON a.DATEDUE = b.DATEDUE  
AND a.OrderID <> b.OrderID
GROUP BY a.OrderID, a.InstalmentID, a.InstalmentSatus, a.DateDue
ORDER BY a.DATEDUE
```

even the result and speed is same if you are using index in your table, you can use distinct for make it simple :

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.OrderID, a.InstalmentID, a.InstalmentSatus, a.DateDue
FROM ORDER_INSTALMENT AS a INNER JOIN ORDER_INSTALMENT AS b
ON a.DATEDUE = b.DATEDUE  
AND a.OrderID <> b.OrderID
ORDER BY a.DATEDUE
```

Comment: The group by clause is redundant in your query.

Comment: Thank you... I will switch to first query back, your second query is good ;)

Comment: all the other instalments are showing. I only need the problem instalments to show.. I.E the ones with the SAME date. thanks

Comment: still don't need the group by, all you had to do is add the second condition to the on clause...

Comment: @PriceCheaperton : Check again ;)

Comment: @ZoharPeled : the result will be doubled if not grouped by

Comment: then use distinct... it's much simpler and has the same effect :-)

Comment: I dont need the other instalments to show. I need only  the dates that are the same...

Comment: @PriceCheaperton : Show us the result you expect!

Comment: IF I have 10 instalments, then i only want to see the instalments with the SAME date.. In my original post, i have shown my results.

Comment: the query will show the records with same date (more than 1). You just give result without sample data. What's wrong with the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use exists or an inner join:

```
SELECT *
FROM ORDER_INSTALMENT o
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM ORDER_INSTALMENT i
    WHERE o.DATEDUE = i.DATEDUE
    AND i.<UniqueColumnName> <> o.<UniqueColumnName>
)
```

Or

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM ORDER_INSTALMENT t1
INNER JOIN ORDER_INSTALMENT t2
ON t1.DATEDUE = t2.DATEDUE
AND t1.<UniqueColumnName> <> t2.<UniqueColumnName>
```

Please note that you need to change `<UniqueColumnName>` to a column name that is unique in your table.

Another option:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT DATEDUE, COUNT(*) As NumberOfRows
    FROM ORDER_INSTALMENT 
    GROUP BY DATEDUE
)
SELECT *
FROM ORDER_INSTALMENT t
INNER JOIN CTE
ON t.DATEDUE = CTE.DATEDUE
WHERE NumberOfRows > 1
```